# Keystone keystone.ts: Couldn't find a Program

Tags: node.js, babeljs, keystone

After installation step of yarn, keystone.js is having issues with doing postinstall. It might be related to the babel issue.

```
at Scope.getProgramParent (/user-service/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:391266)
at Scope.crawl (/user-service/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:389859)
at Scope.init (/user-service/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:389648)
at NodePath.setScope (/user-service/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:318551)
at NodePath.setContext (/user-service/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:318706)
at NodePath.popContext (/user-service/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:319657)
at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/user-service/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:311327)
at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/user-service/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:310771)
at TraversalContext.visit (/user-service/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:311441)
at traverseNode (/user-service/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/babel/bundle.js:1910:396041) {
```

code: 'BABEL_TRANSFORM_ERROR'

Comment: Also coming across this error

Comment: Hard to reproduce this without more info. What version of node and yarn are you on (`node --version`, `yarn --version`)? What OS? Can you list the commands you've run start to finish to produce this error? Your title says "couldn't find a program" but that doesn't match the error info you've shared. Can you update your question to include the entire error block?